# Rails config/local_env.yml vs .env vs bashrc environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I was reading from this [article](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) that you can create a `config/local_env.yml` with environment variables and then use `config/application.rb` to read it to replace/take priority before the environment variables that you export in your `.bashrc`. What then is the `.env` used for then? Does it serve the same purpose as the `config/local_env.yml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these methods are used to feed environment variables to your rails application. So, from an app's point of view, it serves the same purpose whether you export it from `.env` or `.bashrc` or `config/local_env.yml` files.

The differences in these methods are really a matter of personal choice among the team members involved in maintaining the app's development and deployment environments. However, here are few things to consider while opting for either of these choices.

**`.bashrc`** - Use this if you manually configure deployment servers and really comfortable with linux/unix command line system administration. This configuration file is specific to bash shell (Bourne Again Shell). You need to configure different file if your server uses different shell (for example: `.zshrc` if it uses Z Shell)

**`.env`** - Use this if you want to keep your app centric environment variables within the app itself while maintaining different variations of environment variables for different runtime environments of your rails app. For example: `.env.development` and `.env.test` files with specific values of the environment variables for your development and test environments respectively. This gives you more control of your app's environment variables and do not have to rely on the platform (terminal shell) you want to deploy your app.

**`config/local_env.yml`** - This is similar to `.env` approach, which is provided out of the box by rails gem that allows you to configure environment variables for your app in yml format. This method also keeps your app's configuration within the app irrespective of the shell you are using to run your app.

Comment: Thanks @sa77! On a follow-up question, when you deploy your app, how does the server know to use your .env.production file? Where is that set?

Comment: @mangocaptain you just need to have  all your configurations on `.env.production` and have `RAILS_ENV=production` and have these lines: `require 'dotenv'` folowed by `Dotenv.load` on your `config/environments/production.rb` file for this to work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, another downside of using .bashrc is that it is specific to only one user, so if you're e.g. starting your app server as a systemd service then I believe it won't see your variables.

Meanwhile, .env's [Github readme](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#can-i-use-dotenv-in-production) says that it is not the most recommended thing to use outside of the development environment, although it is OK for that purpose.

Another two options to consider are:

1. [Rails secrets](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security). The benefit of this approach is that you get to commit it to git since it's encrypted, so when working in a team you will all have access to the same file. The downside is that it is coupled to the RAILS_ENV variable, so you can't use it to set that e.g. to production on your production app (but you can manually pass it every time it's invoked). Another downside is that if you have a staging environment, then apparently [Heroku discourages using RAILS_ENV=staging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57476097/1466212), which you sometimes really need, so if you need it then you can either do it anyway, or you'll need to set the differing variables via a different mechanism - for example my app has a variable which points to the URL of another part of my app, this URL needs to point to its staging variant on staging, and to its production variant on production, so it needs to differ between my production and staging environment.
2. Using an /etc/environment file - note that systemd services don't have access to it by default so you'd have to add the line `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment`. Also if you're running a shell script from a non-login shell (which happens sometimes), they it won't load them either, but the solution is to just include in your script this: `set -a; source /etc/environment; set +a`. You should be careful not to commit this to git. If you're working in a team and you need to manage this file then it gets a little complicated since it's not committed to git, but maybe there's a way to have it encrypted. (systemd services note: you might optionally use [`LoadCredential=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LoadCredential=ID:PATH) for sensitive variables such as private keys, so that other processes won't have access to them; if you do this then you can also commit to git /etc/environment which should now contain non-sensitive variables only).

In my opinion both of those are valid and it's fine to pick whatever is easier to do in your app.