# Are there any reasons not to use RAILS_ENV=staging on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, staging

The Heroku documentation at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-to-a-custom-rails-environment says I shouldn't use a staging.rb file to define my staging environment.

> It may be tempting to create another custom environment such as “staging” and create a config/environments/staging.rb and deploy to a Heroku app with RAILS_ENV=staging.
>
> This is not a good practice. Instead we recommend always running in production mode and modifying any behavior by setting your config vars.

I think this is terrible advice and conflicts with well-established Rails best practice. However, I'm not here to argue about best practices. I'm here to ask:

Are there any reasons not to use RAILS_ENV=staging on Heroku?

Is there anything that will break if I create a staging.rb file and set the xxx_ENV config vars like this?

```
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging --remote staging
heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=staging --remote staging
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't anything that will break if you do this.

However, I do think that Heroku is right here (note that I work at Heroku).
It introduces possible differences between your staging and production environments, when the only thing that changes between them should be configuration variables.
Heroku already provides a secure mean of setting configuration variables, with the `config:set` command.
Using 2 config files means you have to maintain the same configuration twice, and possible can have issues because you updated the configuration correctly in staging, but incorrectly in production.

As a side note, `RACK_ENV` should only ever have 3 values: `production`, `development` and `none`. See https://www.hezmatt.org/~mpalmer/blog/2013/10/13/rack_env-its-not-for-you.html

Comment: Thanks for the note about RACK_ENV. I had never set RACK_ENV before but noticed it in several answers to other questions about Heroku on Stack Overflow. I didn't think to question it and will set it back to `production`.

Comment: When I have multiple production-ish environments, I factor out the common code into a production_common.rb file. What's left is custom domain stuff (rather than rails config per se) like the hostname, the email addresses to notify, the google analytics ID to use, allow_robots etc. I find it easier to have all that stuff in one place so I can manage it through source control and easily diff one environment with another.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get some warnings from Heroku when you deploy, but I can confirm I did run staging apps, with `RAILS_ENV=staging`, on Heroku. As long as you set the correct environment variables and `Gemfile` groups, it should just work.

My guess is that the reason they advise not to use custom environments is that they have some operational tooling that assumes your Rails app runs in `production` environment, but so far I didn't run into issues.