# Rails encrypted credentials with Heroku staging environment (using production setting)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, credentials, ruby-on-rails-6

Heroku [recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-to-a-custom-rails-environment#setting-staging-behavior) *not* using a custom environment called `staging`; instead, they suggest using the `production` environment but with a different set of `ENV` variables.  This makes sense ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476097/are-there-any-reasons-not-to-use-rails-env-staging-on-heroku)).

However, I am wondering how I can integrate this practice with [Rails 6 encrypted credentials](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials) feature.  Encrypted credentials *does* support multiple environments, so we can keep our `development` and `production` credentials separate; however, using Heroku's recommendation would mean that the `production` credentials would be shared between the actual production server and the actual staging server.  Which I don't want.

What I do want is the `staging` server to use the `development` credentials in the `production` environment!

Keeping all the different credentials uploaded and up to date (between production, staging, and all our developers) is a hassle and the encrypted file seems like an much needed improvement; I just can't sort out how to get staging to use the non-production crednetials.

---

PS: perhaps one could override the `config.credentials.content_path` [per the docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-credentials) based on an environmental variable set in Heroku that indicates whether to use the production or development credentials.  Curious what others are doing or might do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Overriding is the solution indeed. Here's my setup.

Since `RAILS_ENV` is set to `production` per Heroku's recommendation, I use another environment variable that I called `PIPE_ENV` and which is set to the position in the pipeline, so  `staging`, `edge` (for development), etc.

Now in `application.rb`, I set the content_path.

```
module MyAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    …
    if ENV["PIPE_ENV"].present?
      Rails.application.config.credentials.content_path = Rails.root.join("config/credentials/#{ENV["PIPE_ENV"]}.yml.enc")
    end
  end
end
```

I don't like having things in here but `config/environments/production.rb` uses credentials to set the mailer, so it has to be set earlier.

Also, don't forget to set the RAILS_MASTER_KEY to the corresponding environment, so for staging you call

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=your-staging-key -a your-staging-app
```

Of course, `your-staging-key` is the string in `config/credentials/staging.key`

Bonus, for the rest of your app, you can add this in `config/initializer/pipe_env.rb` so that you can call `Rails.pipe_env` just like you call `Rails.env`:

```
module Rails
  class << self
    def pipe_env
      @_pipe_env = ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["PIPE_ENV"].presence || Rails.env)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In `application.rb`, you can also set `key_path`, so that testing `PIPE_ENV=staging rails c` or `PIPE_ENV=staging rails s` also works in your development setup.


And `Rails.application.config.credentials.content_path` can actually be reduced to `config.credentials.content_path`.

Comment: ```
```
module MyAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    …
    if ENV["PIPE_ENV"].present?
      config.credentials.key_path = Rails.root.join("config/credentials/#{ENV['PIPE_ENV']}.key")
      config.credentials.content_path = Rails.root.join("config/credentials/#{ENV['PIPE_ENV']}.yml.enc")
    end
  end
end
```